# Laravel Elixir & Gulp - File not defined in asset manifest

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

Everytime I run `gulp`, I get no warning messages in the console, only when I re-vist my Laravel application:

> File js/vendor.js not defined in asset manifest. (View:
>   /Users/Documents/app/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View:
>   /Users/Documents/app/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

My `gulpfile.js` setup is:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {

mix.scripts([
    '../bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    '../bower/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
], 'public/js/vendor.js')
.version(["js/vendor.js", "build/vendor"]);


mix.scripts([
    '../bower/holderjs/holder.js',
    '../bower/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js',
    '../bower/jasny-bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.js'
], 'public/js/addConsultant.js')
.version(["js/addConsultant.js", "build/addConsultant"]);

});
```

The output from running the `gulp` command is:

> [16:12:44] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/compare/gulpfile.js [16:12:44]
>   Starting 'default'... [16:12:44] Starting 'scripts'...
>
> Fetching Scripts Source Files...
>      - resources/assets/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js
>      - resources/assets/bower/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
>
> Saving To...
>      - public/js/vendor.js
>
> [16:12:45] Finished 'default' after 844 ms [16:12:45] gulp-notify:
>   [Laravel Elixir] Scripts Merged! [16:12:45] Finished 'scripts' after
>   1.02 s [16:12:45] Starting 'version'...
>
> Fetching Version Source Files...
>      - public/js/vendor.js
>      - public/build/vendor/**/*
>
> Saving To...
>      - public/build
>
> [16:12:45] Finished 'version' after 51 ms [16:12:45] Starting
>   'scripts'...
>
> Fetching Scripts Source Files...
>      - resources/assets/bower/holderjs/holder.js
>      - resources/assets/bower/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js
>      - resources/assets/bower/jasny-bootstrap/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.js
>
> Saving To...
>      - public/js/addConsultant.js
>
> [16:12:46] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Scripts Merged! [16:12:46]
>   Finished 'scripts' after 201 ms [16:12:46] Starting 'version'...
>
> Fetching Version Source Files...
>      - public/js/addConsultant.js
>      - public/build/addConsultant/**/*
>
> Saving To...
>      - public/build
>
> [16:12:46] Finished 'version' after 55 ms

Inside the `public/build/rev-manifest.json` file is the following:

> {   "js/addConsultant.js": "js/addConsultant-4f9f7941f8.js" }

Why am I getting this error? Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Is this eventually your problem? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/file-publiccssallcss-not-defined-in-asset-manifest